# Create flat structure for parent/child relation

Tags: sql, t-sql

[image: Input]

I have a Parent/Child relation ship table upto 10 levels as defined above and need output as per below screenshot that will be in a flat structure.

[image: Output]

Below is the code to create table and insert sample data.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.CCTemp
(
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
CCName VARCHAR(100),
[Level] INT,
ParentID INT
)

INSERT INTO DBO.CCTemp (CCName,Level,ParentID) values ('Services Total - 2018',1,NULL)
INSERT INTO DBO.CCTemp (CCName,Level,ParentID) values ('2018_9UKDT - UKD Expense Total',2,1)
INSERT INTO DBO.CCTemp (CCName,Level,ParentID) values ('2018_9Q400 - UKD Indirects',3,2)
INSERT INTO DBO.CCTemp (CCName,Level,ParentID) values ('98064 - IT SDS Costs',4,3)
INSERT INTO DBO.CCTemp (CCName,Level,ParentID) values ('98063 - ACS in charges',4,3)
INSERT INTO DBO.CCTemp (CCName,Level,ParentID) values ('98012 - UKD - Central',4,3)
INSERT INTO DBO.CCTemp (CCName,Level,ParentID) values ('2018_9Q300 - UKD Non Opex Total',3,2)
INSERT INTO DBO.CCTemp (CCName,Level,ParentID) values ('98024 - Commission',4,7)
INSERT INTO DBO.CCTemp (CCName,Level,ParentID) values ('98013 - Affiliates Commission',4,7)
INSERT INTO DBO.CCTemp (CCName,Level,ParentID) values ('2018_9Q200 - Digital Functions Total',3,2)
INSERT INTO DBO.CCTemp (CCName,Level,ParentID) values ('2018_9QB41 - Marketing',4,10)
INSERT INTO DBO.CCTemp (CCName,Level,ParentID) values ('2018_9QB4F - UKD Marketing General Function',5,11)
INSERT INTO DBO.CCTemp (CCName,Level,ParentID) values ('98141 - Marketing Stratey, Planning and Supplier Management',6,12)
INSERT INTO DBO.CCTemp (CCName,Level,ParentID) values ('98031 - UKD Cost Challenge (RM)',6,12)
```

Comment: You could do 9 left joins or use a recursive cte with a pivot.

Comment: Hey @JonathanWilson, I will give a try for this one, initially i had created Pivot on Level column but facing challenge while combining the parent and child from couple of rows to one.

Comment: Could you explain the second result, please. It's not quite clear what is shown there.

Comment: A better question is WHY do you need this? Its a SQL anti-pattern.  If you ever have a tree deeper that 10, it won't fit in to your flat format. The flat file has massive repetition of data. It's expensive to generate, slow to search, difficult to maintain, etc, etc. If you show us what you're intending to use this for, perhaps we can help you with alternative design patterns.

Comment: Hey @MatBailie, I need to have the specific requirement mentioned in the output screen shot from the team and it is one time activity every quarter and only 10 levels.

Comment: If the requirement was "use 100% cpu and fill the disk", would you do that?  You should be asking the team why this is needed, how it will be used, how it fits in the design, whether there are alternatives, etc, etc. In my teams I don't keep people who don't ask questions, I let them go and replace them.

Comment: @MatBailie I think it would be an anti-pattern pattern to *store* data that way but is it really an anti-pattern to generate a *report* in that format? I don't think so. It can be useful to visualize the hierarchy in such a way, despite any duplication.

Comment: Yes @JonathanWilson, used for Visualisation.

Comment: Hey @MatBailie, I would request you not to divert the conversation or the solution required as mentioned.

Comment: I would request you to appreciate 20+ years of experience that is trying to help you not waste your time and effort, and possibly the time of those in your team. I'm trying to help you avoid a mistake I've seen people make before. I'm trying to help you solve the real need, not the perceived approach. Whether you choose to pass on that opportunity is your choice, but I will ***not*** choose to refrain from offering it to you. Not raising these issues would be negligent on my part.

Comment: Hey @MatBailie, I really appreciate your time on this and suggestion of inputs based on your experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  L0.CCNAME,
  L1.CCNAME,
  L2.CCNAME,
  L3.CCNAME,
  L4.CCNAME,
  L5.CCNAME,
  L6.CCNAME,
  L7.CCNAME,
  L8.CCNAME,
  L9.CCNAME
FROM
            dbo.CCTemp AS L0
  LEFT JOIN dbo.CCTemp AS L1 ON L1.parentID = L0.id
  LEFT JOIN dbo.CCTemp AS L2 ON L2.parentID = L1.id
  LEFT JOIN dbo.CCTemp AS L3 ON L3.parentID = L2.id
  LEFT JOIN dbo.CCTemp AS L4 ON L4.parentID = L3.id
  LEFT JOIN dbo.CCTemp AS L5 ON L5.parentID = L4.id
  LEFT JOIN dbo.CCTemp AS L6 ON L6.parentID = L5.id
  LEFT JOIN dbo.CCTemp AS L7 ON L7.parentID = L6.id
  LEFT JOIN dbo.CCTemp AS L8 ON L8.parentID = L7.id
  LEFT JOIN dbo.CCTemp AS L9 ON L9.parentID = L8.id
```

Comment: You were so against this whole question and then you go and post an answer! Nine left joins lol

Comment: @JonathanWilson That's the insanity of the question. I posted it in an attempt to draw that point out. I'm not against anything, I'm trying to ask more questions, to search deeper, to find the underlying need, to help the OP better. I'm trying to help.

Comment: I totally get it and I appreciate it.  That said, your characterization of this report as an anti-pattern is an overstatement and your comment about using "100% cpu and fill the disk" is a straw man.  If someone doesn't accept your recommendation, there's no need to punch their lights out :p

Comment: Hey @MatBailie, it took one sec to give the output, this is really close and i am looking to work on this forward and would thank you for your effort on this.. Thanks again.

Comment: @Babulal you should at least upvote and accept his answer :)

Comment: @JonathanWilson One of my comments appears to have vanished. My response to the suggestion that this is visualision for a report is to ask where the data is. Few reports have no data. If it's a template, it's not searchable (if you want to report from a L5 node down, or up, good luck), it doesn't have ids to join on, etc, etc.  This appears to be a paraphrase of the real requirement with important aspects missing. I've seen this tried by newer team members before, it's always thrown away and replaced with something parameterised for search and roll up.